# How to Pass value through URL to Html page (contain js snippet)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Low-code platform based on Flutter to develop my app and that platform have Built-in widgets such as (WebView widget "accepts URL") and planning to use it to display [Tradingview Widgets](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/single-ticker/)

**Platform**
[image]

**The widget**

[image: Example]

**singalticker.html** Code

```html
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/?exchange=FX" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">EURUSD Rates</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-single-quote.js" async>
  {
  "symbol": "FX:EURUSD",
  "width": 350,
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "locale": "en"
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

So, I've managed to create a html page in GitHub and publish it and then placed its URL in the WebView and its works BUT what I'm asking is how to pass a value through the URL to change the pair

```
"symbol": "FX:EURUSD",
```

so when the user choose a pair of (Stock/Fiat) the html page changes depends on that ?
I've tried following multiple solutions here but nothing works !

**Any help in this matter will be appreciated thanks**

Comment: Why you cant use query params? Then parse them with JS when document is loaded? Like ...? Symbol=FX:eurusd

Comment: you can look in window.location direction https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: thanks for responding .... I've tried the what you've suggested BUT once I change the code between the brackets {} in the script it doesn't work... I've added these lines to my code `const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);`   `const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());`  `"symbol": params.pairs,` But the result is the widget resetting to the default stats which means it didn't works !

Comment: @hamaronooo 
@ I-vasilich-I
I'm not expert in Html or Javascript...any help is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you can get query variable from URL string;

```
// add this function in your page script
function GetQueryVar(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1)
    var vars = query.split('&')
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var qPair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(qPair[0]).toLowerCase() == variable.toLowerCase())
            return decodeURIComponent(qPair[1]);
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
// url is: https://siteurl.com/page?fx=EURUSD
const fx = GetQueryVar('FX') // fx == 'EURUSD'
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
<body>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
        <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright" id="view"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
            var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }
        const container = document.getElementById("view")
        const symbol = getParameterByName('fx')
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
            iframe.setAttribute(
                'src',
                `https://s.tradingview.com/embed-widget/single-quote#{"width":350,"symbol":"FX:${symbol}","isTransparent":false,"height":126,"utm_source":"","utm_medium":"widget","utm_campaign":"single-quote"}`,
            );
            iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no')
            iframe.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true')
            iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0)
            iframe.setAttribute('style', 'box-sizing: border-box; height: calc(94px); width: 350px;')
            container.appendChild(iframe)
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi...I've tried your code and its working with demo script But it doesn't work with the tradingview script that I shared above .. when I add any line inside the tradingview script "Between the Brackets {}" it doesn't execute!!! ..... I've also tried to create a separate script above the tradingview script and put inside of it the function and call it in tradingview script still doesn't work !!

Comment: @Nasser you should to configure all that HTML block provided in question dynamically from your custom script on document loaded.

Comment: really appreciate your help but I'm not expert in html so I don't know what you did meant by that ,,, Can you give a hint about it !?

Comment: @Nasser have high load right now, will write you solution in 1 hour

Comment: @Nasser Check UPDATE 1

Comment: Hi, Do you know that you've been added to my **legends list**!.....IT WORKS ...Thanks for your time and help..you've saved me